# How to auto increment in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How I can auto increment **vidslide1.stopVideo();** in javascript?

**Example,**

vidslide1.stopVideo();

vidslide2.stopVideo();

vidslide3.stopVideo();

...

vidslide10.stopVideo();

**Script:**

```
 $('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
        vidslide1.stopVideo();  
        vidslide2.stopVideo();
        });
```

Comment: create an array containing vidslides and refer by index

Comment: The suggested way is to use arrays. Although you could use the eval() function, like explained in another StackOverlow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5117162/2312381

Comment: Where are these defined?

Comment: I was trying something like this

var i
for(i = 0; 1 < vidslides.length(); i++) {
    var obj = vidslides[i]
    vidslide(i).stopVideo();  
}

but not working. and breaking the slider cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to arrays

```
var vidarr = [vidslide1,vidslide2,vidslide3];
vidarr.forEach(function(v) { v.stopVideo(); });
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for :)  Thank you so much :)